# Music service is started but song is not playing

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-music-player

I had created music player service which stop automatically on back pressed. I want to set it continuously until songs are available or user manually close from notification window. Any help appreciated.

Here below i put some code which i had created from reference

```
private MediaPlayer player;
    private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        initMusicPlayer();
    }

    public void initMusicPlayer(){
        //set player properties
        player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), 
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        //set listeners
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
    }

    public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
        MusicService getService() { 
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    //activity will bind to service
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return musicBind;
    }

    //release resources when unbind
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
        //player.stop();
        //player.release();
        return false;
    }
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //stopForeground(true);
    }
```

this code is used in activity to bind service 
bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            startService(playIntent);

From above code my service is started but i'm not able to play song directly i had to click on play button

```
public void playSong() {
        player.reset();
        try {
        sendName_image();
        player.setDataSource(URI object);
        player.prepareAsync();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
```

Above method is called on button click

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
        }
` is the problem firstly. You will never know if something goes wrong since you just hide the exception. `e.printStackTrace()` it at least.

Comment: @VladMatvienko there is not error on it

Comment: how do you know if you just ignore the error?

Comment: dude if there is any error then player will be stop or not ?

Comment: `} catch (Exception e) {}` => pro java code. Use this in production environnements and in critical systems for the best results.

Comment: no, since you **ignore the exception**. As I said, at least add the `e.printStackTrace()` oinside the c`catch` block, so you at least see in logs that the exception happens.

Comment: @2Dee, I don't think that asker is proficient in programming enough to understand your sarcasm. I'm afraid that your comment even can harm if he thinks that it is not a sarcasm.

Comment: @VladMatvienko i put catch block with printStackTrace(); but no any error found

Answer (score 1):

you should call `player.start();` to start playing after player prepared

Comment: i had put method but not starting still